# Is there a way to use If statements in Nightwatch to control the test

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightwatch.js

I have a site I am testing with multiple versions. I have some fields that show up in the new version that are not in the old version and vice versa.  I would like to use the same test to test every version.  Is there a way to use if statements in a test?  I was  I was trying to use .execute and set a boolean variable to determine if the field is there and continue one way or the other, but I cannot get the variable out of the execute() command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brendan.
About if statements:

```
module.exports = {
"City select present or not": function (browser) {
    if(info.citySelect)
        browser
            .url(enviroment.app)
            .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
            .click('span.firmsConstructorStep1__citySelectorButtonText')
            .verify.visible('div.firmsConstructorStep1__popup')
            .end();
    else
        browser
            .url(enviroment.app)
            .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
            .click('span.firmsConstructorStep1__citySelectorButtonText')
            .verify.hidden('div.firmsConstructorStep1__popup')
            .end();
}
};
```

And about .execute try use result in callback)

Comment: what is info and how is it populated?